# Search bar returns results for all columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search, redux, redux-saga

There is a seach handler like this:

```
  searchHandler = event => {
    const { getCustomers } = this.props;
    getCustomers({
      name: event.target.value,
      surname: this.props.query.surname,
      city: this.props.query.city,
      nationality: this.props.query.nationality,
      pagination: {
        currentPage: this.props.query.pagination.currentPage,
        totalPages: this.props.query.pagination.totalPages,
      },
    });
  };
```

What it does is that it is situtated on top of a table and filters the table data based on `name`.

As it can be seen `name: event.target.value` and the other ones take their value from query.

My task is to make it perform the search for all filters.

For example, in the old function, if somebody searches for "Jack" it would return all the rows containing "Jack" in `name` field.

The new one should return also the rows which are containing "Jack" in surname, nationality and so on.

My approach was to set all values to `event.target.value`:

```
  searchHandler = event => {
    const { getCustomers } = this.props;
    getCustomers({
      name: event.target.value,
      surname: event.target.value,
      city: event.target.value,
      nationality: event.target.value,
      pagination: {
        currentPage: this.props.query.pagination.currentPage,
        totalPages: this.props.query.pagination.totalPages,
      },
    });
  };
```

Unfortunately, it does not work.

How can it be made to make the search for all fields?

**UPDATE**
The query is build in redux-saga like this:

```
export function* getCustomers({ query }) {
  let urlQuery = '';

  if (query && query.pagination.currentPage) {
    urlQuery += `&page=${query.pagination.currentPage}`;
  }

  if (query && query.name) {
    urlQuery += `&name=${query.name}`;
  }

  if (query && query.surname) {
    urlQuery += `&surname=${query.surname}`;
  }

  if (query && query.city) {
    urlQuery += `&city=${query.city}`;
  }

  if (query && query.nationality) {
    urlQuery += `&nationality=${query.nationality}`;
  }

  try {
    const response = yield call(api.getCustomers, urlQuery);
    yield put(Creators.getCustomersSuccess(response.data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(Creators.getCustomersFailure(error));
  }
}
```

The query is built with AND (&) and I think it should use something like OR (|) but I don't know how to implement it.

If I test it with my approach ( setting `event.target.value` for all) and I write "t" in the searchBar, the API call will look like this which for sure is not correct:

`http://localhost:5000/customers?&page=1&name=t&surname=t&city=t&nationality=t`

On the back-end, in mongoDB, the search is done like this:

```
const aggregateOptions = [];

 // search by name
    if (req.query.name) {
      aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { name: { $regex: req.query.name, $options: 'i' } } });
    }

    // search by nationality
    if (req.query.nationality) {
      aggregateOptions.push({ $match: { nationality: req.query.nationality } });
    }
```

Comment: Is `getCustumers` a GraphQL function or your own?

Comment: There might be a problem with using event.target multiple times in react, instead you might want to make it a variable: `const searchTerm = event.target.value`  and then use it in all the fields.

Comment: I'm not using GraphQL, `getCustomers` is the function that returns the data in a JSON

Comment: I don't think this can be answered without seeing how `getCustomers` functions. It may be it is an `AND` on all the conditions passed whereas you would need it to be `OR`

Comment: @Anthony, I edited the question. You're right, it needs somthing like `OR` but how can that be implemented?

Comment: the query for the API is fine as `&` is used to pass multiple URL parameters; but it still doesn't reveal the inner workings of the `getCustomers` actually on the API which is where the functionality lives for searching for the customers

Comment: edited again, it is done in MongoDB

Comment: I have not used mongodb but looks like you'd need to do something with https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/or/